# Is there a more "ember way" to compute this value?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Note: I am forced by circumstance to use Ember 2.18, but interested if ^3.4 has it if 2.x does not.

I am computing a Boolean based on two other Boolean. Inside the class there is this:

```
userEmail: '',
feedbackText: '',
emailIsValid: match('useEmail', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
feedbackTextIsValid: gte('feedbackText.length', 5),
disableSubmit: computed('emailIsValid', 'feedbackTextIsValid', function() {
  return (!this.get('emailIsValid') || !this.get('feedbackTextIsValid'));
}),
```

In other words, the property `disableSubmit` should be true if `userEmail` is not a valid email or if `feedbackText` is less than 5 characters. It does this properly.

What I am wondering is if I can use something similar to `not` or `match` to return `true` If either of 2 other values is not `true`.

Comment: I can't think of a cleaner way to do this. I also don't really see any issue with this code. If you do this often you could write your own util and use that

Comment: awaesome. Thanks. I just came out of some Python where everything is "this is the python way" and wanted to make sure I wasn't going to anger or frustrate the ember devs who follow me.

Comment: Ember can be quite dogmatic but this seems fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Because of the limited number of macros immediately available in Ember, you could consider using something like [ember-awesome-macros](https://www.emberobserver.com/addons/ember-awesome-macros) (This is a very popular library just FYI).

```
disableSubmit: nand('emailIsValid', 'feedbackTextIsValid'), // nand is the equivalent of an 'or' with inverted inputs
```

**Option 2**

You could try using a mixture of ['or'](https://emberjs.com/api/api/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/or) and `not` as such.

```
emailIsNotValid: not('emailIsValid'),
feedbackTextIsNotValid: not('feedbackTextIsValid'),
disableSubmit: or('emailIsNotValid', 'feedbackTextIsNotValid')
```